# xtab breaking table even though next row could "apparently" fit

Tags: tables, xtab

Below is the MWE for a table spanning multiple pages. I like how this works generally, but the last row is awkwardly left on a lonely page. In the actual document there are many sections more rows, and the ones without text are always treated like the were huge.

What am I missing? Is this just something I have to live with, or is there an alternative markup (still using tables)?

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

% DOCUMENT LAYOUT
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xtab}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{layout}
\geometry{a4paper, right=3cm, textheight=22cm, marginparsep=0.5cm, marginparwidth=3.5cm, left=2cm, footskip=3.5cm}

% XTABLE
% --- For paragraph headings
\newcommand{\doom}[1]{%
\footnotesize{#1}}
% --- For "old section" titles
\newcommand{\dope}[1]{%
\LARGE{#1}}

% TABULAR -- MAKE LINES LESS CRAMPED
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{0.2cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{mpxtabular}{r p{\textwidth}}
&\dope{Hello}\\
\verb|6.5| & \doom{Commitment 4}
\\
&
\lipsum[1]
\\
\\
\verb|6.0| & \doom{Commitment 2}
\\
&
\lipsum[2]
\\
\\
\verb|6.5| & \doom{Commitment 1}
\\
&
\lipsum[1]
\\
\\
\verb|6.0| & \doom{Commitment }
\\
&
\\
\\
\end{mpxtabular}
\end{document}
```

Regards

Comment: `xtab` estimates the current position with a generous overshooting. This is particularly evident if you use a reduced font size for the table.

Comment: Makes sense, but is there any way I can manipulate this?

Comment: @anaheim This worked for me, from the `xtab` manual: The command `\xentrystretch{decimal-fraction}` can be used before a table to modify the amount of vertical space apparently consumed by each entry in the subsequent table(s). The default is `\xentrystretch{0.1}` which species a 10% overestimate in the vertical space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what xtab is doing here but after fixing a few things in your input, this works:

Every line was overfull as the second column was `\textwidth` wide which left nowhere for the first column.

Font size commands such as `\LARGE` need a syntax `{\LARGE#1\par}` not `\LARGE{#1}`

`\tabcolsep` is a length not a macro so should be set with `\setlength`.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

% DOCUMENT LAYOUT
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xtab}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{layout}
\geometry{a4paper, right=3cm, textheight=22cm, marginparsep=0.5cm, marginparwidth=3.5cm, left=2cm, footskip=3.5cm}

% XTABLE
% --- For paragraph headings
\newcommand{\doom}[1]{%
{\footnotesize#1\par}}
% --- For "old section" titles
\newcommand{\dope}[1]{%
{\LARGE#1\par}}

% TABULAR -- MAKE LINES LESS CRAMPED
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.2cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{mpxtabular}{p{42pt} p{\dimexpr\textwidth-42pt - 4\tabcolsep\relax}}
&\dope{Hello}\\
\verb|6.5| & \doom{Commitment 4}\\
&
\lipsum[1]\\
\mbox{}\\
\verb|6.0| & \doom{Commitment 2}\\
&
\lipsum[2]\\
\mbox{}\\
\verb|6.5| & \doom{Commitment 1}\\
&
\lipsum[1]\\
\mbox{}\\
\verb|6.0| & \doom{Commitment }%
\end{mpxtabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thats beautiful! What is the mbox{} in the table for? Cheers

Comment: @user27293 the `mbox{}` puts things in a bit more stable state before `\\` I'm not sure they are needed now with the other changes but I added them originally to the example and they seemed to help xtab a bit.